# What's the best way to name e-learning modules?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm creating an e-learning template and I'm struggling on how to make the modules and name them in the most efficient way. My idea is to have a shell that calls in each course module - the module being one FLA containing scenes for the lessons and pages. Generally, courses are setup to have the following depth:

- **Module 1**

  - Lesson 1

    - Page 1
    - Page 2
    - Page 3
  - Lesson 2

    - Page 1
    - Page 2
- **Module 2**

  - Lesson 1

    - Page 1
    - Page 2
    - Page 3
  - Lesson 2

    - Page 1
    - Page 2

And right now my idea is to name the files like so `1_2_3.swf`. `1` would indicate module 1, `2` would indicate lesson 2, and `3` would indicate page 3. This seems to be the best way, but I wanted to get some feedback from someone who has experience with creating e-learning templates and see if there could be issues down the road or a more efficient way to do this.

If it will help, here is my folder/file structure:

[image: Folders]
[image]

Comment: Your idea seems ok. I would add a description after the numbers, like "1_1_2_mathlesson". It would make them easier to find while browsing. Are you listing the files in another file (code or xml)?

Comment: Hey Emil, yeah they are listed in an xml file then imported to build the navigation. I wanted to find some type of standard for the naming convention, but it seems us e-learning developers are left to our own devices ;-)

Comment: Well, I've been working in an e-learning company for 6 years now, and we don't have any naming convention. We should, but we don't. Maybe SCORM is providing some kind of advice about that.

Comment: I agree with Emil Schn about the description.  I would also add zeros before the numbers, such as 01_01_001.  The number of zeros would depend on the maximum number of modules, lessons or pages you expect.  This would keep the files sorted nicely.  As far as I remember, SCORM doesn't provide a naming convention either.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with e-learning modules for over 10 years. We adopted a rigid file-naming convention that was a bit hard to adopt at first because of the overhead, but really simplified our lives at the end. We assign 9 digit part numbers to each module, first n characters determine a category (if that applies to you). We have another category for storyboards, and another for assets. The next n digits are the actual ID for each module, and the last couple are used for variations of the module (i.e. same module in a different language or for a different platform). We put module files in dedicated module folders like you have. The folder name has the part number, followed by the Revision letter or number, and then a short description. Files inside the folder are just using the part numbers and revs. All parts of the file/folder names are separated either by dashes or underscores, no spaces as that messes things up on various platforms.

We also keep track of all part-numbers in a log book / spreadsheet. This makes things so much easier to track who made what module when and what version is the latest. I highly recommend it, especially if you will be re-using modules (i.e. SCORM) and creating many versions of the modules.

For your particular example, when it is time to publish a course/shell I would not use the Description in the folder name to make it easier to update the shell in the future by just changing the Rev letters/numbers in the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Your system would work but it has a couple of problems:

- your files might get sorted as 1_1, 1_10, 1_11, 1_2, 1_3, 1_4 and so on. Most modern file browsers can sort such files "in a human way", i.e. using the full number, not just by character, so it is not likely to become a *real* problem.
- at some point, you will need to add pages IN BETWEEN existing pages and/or chapters. What will you do to add two news pages between 2_2_5 and 2_2_6?
- as mentioned previously, your names have no indication of content - add something like 3_1_1_intro, 3_2_1quiz.
- similarly, you will end up using a lot of templates, because most e-learning pages are like each other. Are you going to just clone FLA files? What if you need to change a single color in each of those? Will you open and re-publish 20 cloned FLAs?

You have chosen a primitive but very time-intensive way of development. I suggest you consider working with a player shell, page templates and XML content.

Answer (score 0):

Advancement in technology has not only revolutionized how businesses operate but it has also impacted the education sector greatly.

In addition, eLearning is slowly replacing the traditional classes and teaching methods. This is because most people are slowly discovering the benefits of this mode of learning.

While the most obvious ones are cost savings and flexibility, in this guide, we define what is e learning and its benefits to both tutors and learners.

More Info - http://tutorroom.net/e-learning/what-is-e-learning/